# Can't load images in laravel blade files

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I've downloaded a template from [here](https://github.com/puikinsh/kiaalap.git).

I want to design pages like that in `laravel` blade pages, I put `css` and `js` files in public folder and link blade files to them, and it works.

But I can't handle images, there isn't a folder for images in this template and I don't know how to load them in my blade pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can upload images on below path

```
storage/app/public/images

//this way you can use in your blade file   

<img src = "{{ asset('/images/YOUR_IMAGE.png') }}" />
```

but you need to run one command

```
php artisan storage:link
```

it will create a symlink from public/storage to storage/app/public

Comment: If your blade is pointed in api.php which makes path like /api/something the image won't load, it looks for /api/images/yourfile. How can I make it point to an absolute path or something?

Answer (score 0):

please insert as below path and make link like that.
try this.

```
<div class="hidden-xs" style="width:200px; height:auto; margin-left:-10px;">
   <img src="{{ asset('uploads/logos/myLogo.png') }}">
</div>
```

If not working... then check your App Url in `/.env` and restart your app server.

```
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

Happy coding~!:)