# How to display storage image in laravel blade?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have stored my image with following code

```
if (isset($image)) {
    // make unique name for image
    $currentDate = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
    $imagename = $slug . '-' . $currentDate . '-' . uniqid() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

    // check category dir is exists
    if (!Storage::disk('public')->exists('category')) {
        Storage::disk('public')->makeDirectory('category');
    }
    // resize image for category and upload
    $category = Image::make($image)->resize(1600,479)->stream();
    Storage::disk('public')->put('category/'.$imagename,$category);
    // check category slider dir is exists
    if (!Storage::disk('public')->exists('category/slider')) {
        Storage::disk('public')->makeDirectory('category/slider');
    }
    // resize image for category slider and upload
    $slider = Image::make($image)->resize(500,333)->stream();
    Storage::disk('public')->put('category/slider/'.$imagename,$slider);
} else {
    $imagename = "default.png";
}
```

try with this code

```
<img src="images/icons8-team-355979.jpg" alt="Profile Image">
```

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
this is the error

Comment: Check  -> https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#configuration and set link to acces publicly.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36066144/how-should-i-serve-an-image-with-laravel/36477345#36477345

Comment: You can check here [storage images to access in blade files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54142037/7478838) this may help you.

Comment: You can check it here [storage images to access in blade files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54142037/7478838) may this could help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<img src="{{url('category/slider')}}/{{ $category->image }}" alt="{{$category->name}}">
```

The url function will go to '/public' folder. So, you may need to edit your '/config/filesystem.php' so that the uploaded photo is saved inside the '/public' directory.

For more information on this please check this [document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem).

Comment: Sorry sir :( 
I have tried with this code
<img src="{{ Storage::disk('public')->url('category/slider/'.$category->image) }}" alt="{{ $category->name }}">

Comment: You don't need to use 'Storage::disk('public')' in blade view. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Check if your picture is saved on '/public/category/slider' directory. Can you please share your 'config/filesystem.php'

Comment: <?php

return [ 'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),
    'disks' => [
        'local' => ['driver' => 'local','root' => storage_path('app'),],
        'public' => [ 'driver' => 'local', 'root' => storage_path('app/public'),url' =>env('APP_URL').'/storage','visibility' => 'public',
        ],'s3' => ['driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
  ],

    ],

];

Comment: change 'disks->public->root' from 'storage_path('app/public')' to 'public_path()'

Answer (score 0):

When you want to serve files from the public disk directly, you need to create a symlink to these files. This is described in the documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#the-public-disk.

When you have done this, you can link to the assets using the `asset()` function.

```
echo asset('category/slider/icons8-team-355979.jpg');
```

Comment: images in storage->app->public->category->slider folder

Comment: That should work fine, but you have to use the correct relative path for the asset function.